# Get device name python

Tags: python, flask

How can I get the device name on deployed app with python?

I've already tried socket.gethostname() and platform.node() , but both are returning the machine name where the app is deployed , not the machine from where the app is reached.

The app is deployed on Heroku.

```py
def sessions():
   userName = platform.node()
```

I've expected the userName to be for ex. `'Jonh-ThinkPad-A485'` , but the userName is `'046ee322-ee28-4a25-b789-ef005ac0e172'`

Comment: are you trying to get the clients device/computer name from the server-side (Heroku)?

Comment: @Faris yes, I'm trying to get the name on the server side.